# Reset certain values every day at certain time

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdate

In my application, I have an array of to-do objects. And every day at a certain time, lets say 13 PM, the array of to-do objects has to be modified.
What kind of functions can I use to trigger this event every day?

Comment: you can yous the cron job set on the server while using the webservices on

Comment: I'm not using any webservices so far. I would like the values to be reset even without any internet connection.

Comment: ok!! I am not an ios developer but worked on the webservices which is used for the ios and cron job is set on the server where we can trigger any   event with date time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app is in the foreground, you could set a timer to fire when a certain time threshold passes.
If the app is in the background when the time passes, you could check upon next launch of the app if the threshold has passed, and then do your modifications at that time.

For example, to add the timer add this in your AppDelegate:

```
    private var myTimer: Timer? 

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    myTimer?.invalidate()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    //Scheduling for 1 PM (13:00)
    var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute, .hour, .month, .day, .year], from: Date())
    dateComponents.hour = 13
    dateComponents.minute = 00
    dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone.current

    if let timerDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents) {
        myTimer = Timer(fireAt: timerDate, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFired), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    if let myTimer = myTimer {
        RunLoop.current.add(myTimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
    }
}

func timerFired() {
   //Do you update here
}
```

You could add an additional check in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method to check if your modification has already been done for the day, in case the threshold passes while the app is in the background or inactive.

Comment: Actually, I decided just to do it as you told. I'm setting a Date object every time when the App gets accessed in my UserDefaults. Then I just check everytime when I reopen the app if the new access date is the same day as the lastDate in my userDefaults, and modify my to do objects when they're not the same day. Works fine now!!